# React: Access ref passed between components via render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to access a `ref` passed between two external components using render props ([real example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window-infinite-loader#example-usage)). Can it be done?

```
function Component() {
  // how to get access to `ref` here?

  return (
    <A>
      {({ref}) => (
        <B ref={ref}/>
      )}
    </A>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need **[React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)**

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children.
>
> This is typically not necessary for most components in the application. However, it can be useful for some kinds of components, especially in reusable component libraries.

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The `ref` render prop is actually badly named, it's not a `ref` but a function to set a ref, so we can just use a inline function (thought this may cause extra renders):

```
function Component() {
  const bRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <A>
      {({ref: setRef}) => (
        <B ref={ref => {
          bRef.current = ref;
          setRef(ref);
        }}/>
      )}
    </A>
  )
}
```